# How to generate documentation from web.config comments

Tags: .net, web-config, web.config-transform

Is it possible to generate documentation from comments inside a web.config file as it possible by XML comments from source files?

I'd like to describe the settings a bit more verbose and create a document directly from the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. I generally put lots of XML comments in the config, and copy the whole file into a Word doc.